Evolution of rigid body system using Impulse Based integration
I have been reading about physics engines, I have a reasonably OK understanding force based models and 6 dof integration.
I'm still confused on how impulse based models work.
What define the equations of motion for impulse based engines? Ex, what is a time step in them?

Obligatory link to the canonical SIGGRAPH paper about momentum-based physics modeling https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~baraff/sigcourse/notesd1.pdf and the for collisions https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~baraff/sigcourse/notesd2.pdf

Does this answer your question? Is this the correct way to integrate orientation given torque and inertia tensor?

I'm basically trying to understand the key differences between the two and the equivalent equations of each.

One integrates $$ \begin{pmatrix}\Delta\boldsymbol{v}\
\Delta\boldsymbol{\omega}
\end{pmatrix}=\int\begin{pmatrix}\boldsymbol{F}/m\
{\rm I}^{-1}\left(\boldsymbol{\tau}-\boldsymbol{\omega}\times{\rm I}\boldsymbol{\omega}\right)
\end{pmatrix}{\rm d}t$$ and the other $$\begin{pmatrix}\Delta\boldsymbol{p}\
\Delta\boldsymbol{L}
\end{pmatrix}=\int\begin{pmatrix}\boldsymbol{F}\
\boldsymbol{\tau}
\end{pmatrix}{\rm d}t$$ where $\begin{pmatrix}\boldsymbol{p}\
\boldsymbol{L}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}m\boldsymbol{v}\
{\rm I}\boldsymbol{\omega}
\end{pmatrix}$ is the momentum vectors.

But how is this fundamentally different? I'm still not seeing it since it appears to basically be a rewriting of the above. I'm guessing it is only relevant to contact interactions? But then the same basic interactions still apply.

You can check and enforce the conservation of momentum with the second approach much easier than with the first approach. It is also simpler as angular acceleration involves two matrix multiplications and one matrix inversion for the mass moment of inertia tensor $I$. Also note that the MMOI tensor needs to be re-oriented from body coordinates to inertial coordinates with $${\rm I} = {\rm R} I_{\rm body} {\rm R}^\intercal$$
